# Getting 403 error in Spring security oauth while accessing application specific urls (access_token is valid and csrf is disabled)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

**UPDATE**

(*Answer by Chids is for the problem that I posted earlier which was getting 403 error for `/oauth/token`. That error is resolved and am stuck at the next step .I have modified the question accordingly.*)

**Problem:**

I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 with Spring security. And I am successful in obtaining the `access_token` by making a post request to `/oauth/token`. 
But when I use this access token to use any other secured url I am getting 403.

I have followed multiple questions on SO but all of them suggest to disable csrf for my problem. Issue is I have already disabled that but still getting error.

Can someone guide me whether I am constructing the post request in a wrong way or whether some config is missing.

**My post request through postman looks like:**

[image]

**Config on google:**

[image]

**Resource Server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(3)
public class Oauth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {     

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     
        http.csrf().disable();

            http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/auth/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()                    
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").authenticated();   

    }
}
```

**Authorization server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer  
public class Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler handler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;



    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {      

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("568176070083-1lc20949a0q58l0rhmq93n95kvu8s5o6.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .secret("lNfK3wOaVibgu96il6WLrkTh")         
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);              

    }   


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(handler)
                .authenticationManager(authManager);
    }       

}
```

**Security Config**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.saml.demo")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin").password("admin123").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .anonymous().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be because, you are disabling all anonymous access in your configure block. You can change it to the following

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/oauth/token/revokeById/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll().and()
                .csrf().disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Comment: Nope. I tried the above config but this config returns a login page even on post request for `/oauth/token` instead of retrieving token and when i remove `formlogin`, it agian gives 403.

Comment: I suspect your resource server's security config is getting picked up since you have set the @Order(3). Try to remove that class and check. Post which you can decide where you want to plugin in your resource server logic

Comment: Thanks man. Actually in my initial config, there was no `Order(3)` and was getting the same problem. I put that annotation after searching for solution. Removing it didn't work but changing the order to 100 did work. I assume the key here was to lower the order of this config

Comment: yes higher the number in @Order , lower would be the precedence

Comment: Can you help me one more time. This time I am successful in obtaining token, but I am not able to access any controller mapped urls. For e.g. I am trying to access a secured url `/auth/myoauth` which just returns "hello". I am getting 403 in it. I have set the Authorization header as Bearer <Access-token>

Comment: I am not sure if it is your requirement, but general recommendation is to have a separate Service for Authorization and Resource. In your case, i understand you have both in the same solution.

Comment: Yes. It's a requirement

Comment: try to add this in the Security config :   .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated() . Not able to think any other solution for this!

Comment: But I want the url to be accessible only if access token is valid

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
```

Comment: The default setting is private String checkTokenAccess = "denyAll()"; So maybe try in AuthorizationServerConfiguration and authenticate yourself, or "permitAll()" if you wish and let anybody use it